# How to increase the precision of result from STAsText() on spatial GEOMETRY data type in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, geometry, spatial

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 that contains a column in type of GEOMETRY called SHAPE. Another column called WKT of the same table has Computed Column Formula defined as:

```
([SHAPE].[STAsText]())
```

[SHAPE] column is used to store a bunch of POINT (longitude and latitude) while [WKT] is used to store its Well-Known Text.

However, the WKT represents lower precision than the actual longitude and latitude.

For example, if x = 142.592896 and y = -38.38580099, its WKT is represented as POINT (142.593 -38.3858). How to make it represented as POINT (142.592896 -38.38580099) instead?

Thanks!!

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: When I try a minimal effort at reproducing this, everything works as expected. Show us some code where these values are inserted.

Answer (score 1):

I think its probably down to the column type your latitude and longitudes are stored in, I think they are probably floats.  You could try changing them to decima(x,y), or even a string if you really wanted.

Please see my example below:

```
DECLARE @X FLOAT =  142.59289600001
DECLARE @Y FLOAT = -38.3858009900001

DECLARE @X2 DECIMAL(28,18) =  142.59289600001
DECLARE @Y2 DECIMAL(28,18)= -38.3858009900001

SELECT 
    a.Geog.STAsText() AS WKT
,   b.Geog.STAsText() AS WKT_2
,   c.Geog.STAsText() AS WKT_3
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT(142.59289600001 -38.3858009900001)', 4326) AS Geog
) a
,
(
    SELECT 
        GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + CAST(@X AS VARCHAR(25)) + ' ' + CAST(@Y AS VARCHAR(25)) + ')', 4326) AS Geog
)b
,
(
    SELECT 
        GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + CAST(@X2 AS VARCHAR(25)) + ' ' + CAST(@Y2 AS VARCHAR(25)) + ')', 4326) AS Geog
)c
```